# Django: Setting up apps on a server

Tags: django

Trying to upload my django app on my obunto slice. The problem I'm facing right now there are a couple of packages I'm using. Which I installed in site packages on my machine. Now when I put them online on the server their sadly not working. Any ideas how to make them work.

p.s I get a error on import

Comment: Are you sure you've installed them somewhere in Django's python path?

Comment: And did you restart Apache? Of course, it would help if you said what the actual error was, rather than leaving us to guess.

Comment: I did install them to django's path they were not working, there was a problem with PYTHONPATH like eliben said, it worked out now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python must have a way to find these packages. Did you use standard installation procedures for them (i.e. `setup.py install`) or copy them in an accessible directory? If you didn't use `setup.py install`, check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. It should contain the directory where your packages are stored. If it doesn't, you can create it.

This is a Python issue really, not a Django issue.

To get more help paste the import error you're getting, as well as the directory structure of where you installed this package.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I placed my files in the same project folder and in the settings I added them as applications and now it works fine :)